# DGV Data binding along with a collection from a "nested" second level property class?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, nested, datasource

It's possible to bind this kind of data structure to a DGV?

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string propertyA { get; set; }
    public string propertyB { get; set; }
    public ClassB propertyC { get; set; }
}

// This class acts like a preset uniform list, just to add extra columns
public class ClassB
{
    public static List<string> namesForEveryClassC { get; private set; } // Also every column header and set by the user
    private List<ClassC> data { get; set; } // Bind this

    public ClassC this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (ClassC item in this.data)
                if (item.name == name)
                    return item;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ClassB()
    {
        foreach (string name in namesForEveryClassC)
            data.Add(new ClassC(name));
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public string name { get; set; } // This is only to identify columns
    public int value { get; set; } // Binded in the DataGridView as a cell and able to be set by the user

    public ClassC(string aName)
    {
        this.name = aName;
        this.value = 0;
    }
}
```

The ClassB is like the next part of the DGV's columns, the static string collection is used as names for the column headers and also editable from the user from a ListBox, what should be binded to every column is the int value from the ClassC.
Basically the DGV should be like...

```
 Class A properties      namesForEveryClassC string items as headers
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+ ... +--------+
| PropertyA | PropertyB | ValueA | ValueB | ValueC | ... | ValueN |
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+ ... +--------+
|    ...    |    ...    |    2   |    4   |   0    |     |    7   |
 Class A values          int values in every ClassC from ClassB collection data
```

Which method should be good? ClassB inherit BindingSource? Use ITypedList interface and a PropertyDescriptor? Manually set every column?

My main problem is to access the value using the indexer of the ClassB.

Comment: An interesting idea but I doubt it can be done. Let's see what the experts suggest..